# What is the reason for this weird behavior of sad instruction?

Tags: c, gcc, sse, simd, avx2

I have implemented a [program](https://github.com/sinusee/Intel-SIMD-Technologies/edit/SAD/SADsse2.c) using SSE2 to compare the `vpsadbw` instruction and `psadbw` of AVX2 and SSE2 respectively. The following code is the SSE2 program:

```
#define MAX1 4096
#define MAX2 MAX1
#define MAX3 MAX1

#define NUM_LOOP 1000000000

double pTime = 0, mTime = 5; 

//global data for sequentila matrix operations
unsigned char a_char[MAX1][MAX2] __attribute__(( aligned(16)));
unsigned char b_char[MAX2][MAX3] __attribute__(( aligned(16)));
unsigned char c_char[MAX1][MAX3] __attribute__(( aligned(16)));
unsigned short int temp[8];


int main()
{
    int i, j, w=0, sad=0;
    struct timespec tStart, tEnd;
    double tTotal , tBest=10000;
    __m128i vec1, vec2, vecT, sad_total;
    sad_total= _mm_setzero_si128();

    do{
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tStart);

        for(i=0; i<MAX1; i++){
            for(j=0; j<MAX2; j+=16){

                vec1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&a_char[i][j]);
                vec2 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&b_char[i][j]);
                vecT = _mm_sad_epu8( vec1 , vec2);
                sad_total = _mm_add_epi64(vecT, sad_total);

                }
            }
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i *)&temp[0], sad_total);
        sad=temp[0]+temp[2]+temp[4]+temp[6];    

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tEnd);
        tTotal = (tEnd.tv_sec - tStart.tv_sec);
        tTotal += (tEnd.tv_nsec - tStart.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
        if(tTotal<tBest)
            tBest=tTotal;
        pTime += tTotal;

    } while(w++ < NUM_LOOP && pTime < mTime);
    printf(" The best time: %lf sec in %d repetition for %dX result is %d matrix\n",tBest,w, MAX1, sad);

    return 0;
}
```

I use `gcc`, `skylake`, `Linux mint`
When I generate the assembly code the inner loop contain some unwanted move operation as follows for SSE2:

```
.L26:
    vmovdqa xmm1, XMMWORD PTR a_char[rcx+rax]
    vpsadbw xmm1, xmm1, XMMWORD PTR b_char[rcx+rax]
    add rax, 16
    vpaddq  xmm3, xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsp]
    cmp rax, 4096
    vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp], xmm3
    jne .L26
```

Since AVX2 generates this assembly code:

```
.L26:
    vmovdqa ymm1, YMMWORD PTR a_char[rcx+rax]
    vpsadbw ymm1, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR b_char[rcx+rax]
    add rax, 32
    vpaddq  ymm2, ymm2, ymm1
    cmp rax, 4096
    jne .L26
```

I don't know the reason of those 2 move instruction which violated the performance significantly.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that it's not accesible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this:

```
_mm_store_si128((__m128i *)&temp[0], sad_total);
```

Clang doesn't mind and makes nice code regardless, but GCC didn't like it (failed heuristics perhaps?)

With that replaced to something that doesn't trigger the "this should be on the stack all the time"-heuristic, GCC makes nicer code, for example: (not tested)

```
    __m128i sad_total = _mm_setzero_si128();
    for(i = 0; i < MAX1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < MAX2; j += 16) {
            __m128i vec1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&a_char[i][j]);
            __m128i vec2 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&b_char[i][j]);
            __m128i vecT = _mm_sad_epu8( vec1 , vec2);
            sad_total = _mm_add_epi64(sad_total, vecT);
        }
    }
    __m128i hsum = _mm_add_epi64(sad_total, _mm_bsrli_si128(sad_total, 8));
    sad = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(hsum);
```

The inner loop now looks like

```
.L2:
    vmovdqa xmm1, XMMWORD PTR a_char[rdx+rax]
    vpsadbw xmm1, xmm1, XMMWORD PTR b_char[rdx+rax]
    add     rax, 16
    vpaddq  xmm2, xmm1, xmm2
    cmp     rax, 4096
    jne     .L2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're directly bypassing the compiler and telling it to use movdqa via _mm_load_si128. It's doing exactly what you're telling it to do. What is the problem here? I also noticed that you're aligning along 16byte boundary, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong (I'm not sure of how **attribute** is implemented on your compiler) but you may get padding as result so that each element will be aligned on a 16byte boundary; if so this will affect the impact of your unrolling. If not then feel free to correct me.

Comment: Those things have to be loaded anyway, so I assume the problem is that the accumulator is spilled to the stack

Comment: The alignment attribute _only_ aligns the _first_ byte (i.e. no padding). That is, the linker/loader will guarantee that the variable has an address, such that, `(((unsigned long) &x[0][0]) % 16) == 0`. Maintaining such alignment [when indexing into the array] is up to usage (i.e. the program code). To work correctly, given `unsigned char a_char[MAX1][MAX2]`, `MAX2` must be a multiple of 16 and when indexing with `a_char[i][j]`, `for (j = 0; j < MAX2; j += 16)` [or equiv] must be used. The actual increment could be a multiple of 16 (e.g. 16, 32, ...)

Comment: Cheers Craig. My concern here is that if you use this for each member of a structure (i.e. __attribute__( aligned(16) ) ), then do a sizeof() on the structure does the reported size increase with changes to the alignment parameter (can't test it now)? Not sure how it effects statically declared arrays though - I guess this where your point comes in. Can't test this to be sure but I used the "equivalent" using VS and there was padding. Just thought it might be worth raising as a word of caution.